# Immediate refresh materialized views (MQT) with OUTER JOIN under DB2

Tags: join, db2, materialized-view

DB2 accepts a materialized view based on an "OUTER JOIN" query, as long it doesn't refresh automatically (REFRESH IMMEDIATE).

I cannot find a simple solution to get round this problem. Perhaps with (a lot of) triggers, but it isn't really nice...

As example, my database is

```
CREATE TABLE PHONEUSER (USERID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(30));
CREATE TABLE PHONECALL (CALLID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, USERID INT, HOUR TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO PHONEUSER VALUES (1, 'Olivier');
INSERT INTO PHONEUSER VALUES (2, 'Arthur');

INSERT INTO PHONECALL VALUES (1,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

and I want each call of each user. If an user has never called, I want a `null` value for him (it has sense in my application):

```
SELECT PU.USERID, CALLID, HOUR FROM PHONEUSER PU LEFT JOIN PHONECALL PC ON PC.USERID=PU.USERID;

USERID  CALLID  HOUR                   
------  ------  -----------------------
     2    null  null                   
     1       1  2013-04-09 16:36:08.952
```

This query runs well, but cannot be used for an MQT with `refresh immediate`:

```
CREATE TABLE CALLLIST AS (SELECT PU.USERID, CALLID, HOUR FROM PHONEUSER PU LEFT JOIN PHONECALL PC ON PC.USERID=PU.USERID) DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED REFRESH IMMEDIATE ;
The fullselect specified for the materialized query table CALLLIST is not valid. Reason code = "10".. SQLCODE=-20058, SQLSTATE=428EC, DRIVER=4.7.85
```

Comment: Which member of the DB2 family are we talking about?  DB2 for i, LUW, or z?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and why?

Comment: My system is a DB2 LUW (under Windows), but does the edition change anything to the problem?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you just pick REFRESH DEFERRED and then refresh the MQT periodically throughout your day?

Comment: Why not REFRESH DEFERRED? Just because my application needs the dataes to be actualized as soon as new dataes come...

Comment: @ChrisAldrich Because that's *entirely* different.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, as the error description for `SQL20058N reason code 10` [states](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql20058n.html), you can't use an outer join with a `refresh immediate` MQT:

```
Explanation

...
10
The REFRESH IMMEDIATE option was specified and the FROM clause referenced more than one table.

User Response

10
Create the materialized query table as REFRESH DEFERRED, or use an inner join without the explicit INNER JOIN syntax.
```

However, if the MQT definition you supply is really this simple (i.e., pre-computing the join), I wonder why you want to create an MQT in the first place?  As you said, performance of the query is good, so why wouldn't you just retain the query as written in the application?
Alternately, you could encapsulate the join logic in a view.

Although I would generally advise against this, if there is some serious performance issue with the join that *can't* be resolved with proper indexing and `RUNSTATS`, you could replicate this immediate update functionality through triggers on the `PHONEUSER` and `PHONECALL` tables that insert records into your `CALLLIST` table:

```
create trigger trg_PhoneUser
    after insert on PHONEUSER
    referencing new as n
    for each row
        insert into PHONECALL (userid) values (n.userid);

create trigger trg_PhoneCall
    after insert on PHONECALL
    referencing new as n
    for each row
    begin
        delete from PHONECALL where userid = n.userid and hour is null;--
        insert into PHONECALL values (n.userid, n.callid, n.hour);--
    end;
```

The first trigger is necessary to handle the outer join (i.e. where a user hasn't made any calls yet).  The second trigger inserts the calls, and also deletes the records inserted by the first trigger (as they are no longer necessary once a record in PHONECALL exists).  You would need to decide how you want to handle deletes in either table (either through triggers or foreign keys with cascading deletes).

Again, I want to stress that this is a *possible* solution, but **I would only use it as a last resort**.  Databases are designed to perform joins efficiently, but this might require some proper design and tuning.  The table structures above should absolutely not require this kind of solution, but I'm working on the assumption that this is not your actual schema.  I am only describing this solution because I can imagine a few edge cases where something like this solution *might* be necessary.

Comment: I meant the query runs "well", not "fast", so a MQT would be a good thing. As you say, we could do it with triggers (3 on each source table) which call REFERESH. But in this case, the complete query will be executed once more. A REFRESH IMMEDIATE materialized view would refresh only the rows which really are concerned by the changes of the master tables.

Comment: We will nevertheless use the solution with the REFRESH in triggers.

Comment: I did not mean that you should use an MQT and execute the `REFRESH TABLE` statement from the triggers. This would be disastrous as `REFRESH TABLE` locks the MQT during the refresh.  I meant to suggest that you could use triggers to INSERT rows into the summary table.